# Reading a large text file with over 130000 line of text

Tags: android, inputstream, bufferedreader, readline, large-files

How can i read a large text file into my Application?
This is my code but it does not work. My code must read a file called list.txt. The code worked only with a file with **only 10.000 lines**.
can someone helps me?
Thanks!

**My code:(Worked with small files, but not with large files)**

```
   private void largefile(){

    String strLine2="";
    wwwdf2 = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream fis2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.list);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));
    if(fis2 != null) {
        try {
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(br2);
            String linenumber = String.valueOf(lnr);

            while ((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                wwwdf2.append(strLine2 + "\n");
            }
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), linenumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wwwdf2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: What's failing with big files? Where's it failing and why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please also paste here the error stacktrace.

Comment: I do not know why this code is failing, because Android ignore the loading of text file or Android is reading very long, so there is no error.

Comment: @OpenSearch did you check logcat? Please paste red lines here.

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka 2019-10-25 19:49:13.363 4832-4832/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-10-25 19:49:13.364 4832-4832/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1

Comment: Provide your entire logcat from where the issue starts. Add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: @HB. That's my entire Logcat(only errors).  There is no issue, but it does't work. I don't know.

Comment: Put debugging logs everywhere between lines in your code and check logcat again. Check if everything you need is being executed. Also I don't think it would be a good idea to make toasts that long. Log the length of the StringBuffer after execution

Comment: **Here is the Answer!** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564335/android-reading-a-large-text-efficiently-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are processing a large file, you should process the data in chunks . Here your file reading is fine but then you keep adding all rows in string buffer and finally passing to Toast.makeText(). It creates a big foot-print in memory. Instead you can read 100-100 lines and call Toast.makeText() to process in chunks. One more thing, use string builder instead of string buffer go avoid unwanted overhead of synchronization. You initializing wwwdf2 variable inside the method but looks it is a instance variable which I think is not required. Declare it inside method to make it's scope shorter.