# Android Reading a large text efficiently in Java

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, bufferedreader

### My code is too slow

How can I make my code efficiently? Currently the code needs several minutes until the file was read, which is way too long. Can this be done faster? There is no stacktrace, because it works, but too slow.
Thanks!

**The Problem Code:**

```
private void list(){
        String strLine2="";
        wwwdf2 = new StringBuffer();

        InputStream fis2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.list);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));
        if(fis2 != null) {
            try {
                LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(br2);
                String linenumber = String.valueOf(lnr);
                int i=0;
                while (i!=1) {
                    strLine2 = br2.readLine();
                    wwwdf2.append(strLine2 + "\n");
                    String contains = String.valueOf(wwwdf2);
                    if(contains.contains("itisdonecomplet")){
                       i++;
                    }
                }
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strLine2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wwwdf2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `if(contains.contains("itisdonecomplet"))` Better:  `if(strLine2.contains("itisdonecomplet"))`. But why do you need that? Is that the ;last line? Then remove that check as after the last line readLine() will return null,

Comment: @blackapps There is the Problem. Readline() returns null even before the file is red complet.

Comment: THat is hard to believe. Never seen such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

   `StringBuffer` is synchronized, and you don't need that.
2. Don't use `String.valueOf`, which builds a string, negating the value using a `StringBuffer`/`Builder`. You are building a string from the whole buffer, checking it, discarding the string, then constructing nearly the same string again.

   Use `if (wwwdf2.indexOf("itisdonecomplet") >= 0)` instead, which avoids creating the string.

   But this will still be reasonably slow, as although you would not be constructing a string and searching through it all, you are still doing the searching.

   You can make this a lot faster by only searching the very end of the string. For example, you could use `wwwdf2.indexOf("itisdonecomplet", Math.max(0, wwwdf2.length() - strLine2.length() - "itisdonecomplet".length()))`.

   Although, as blackapps points out in a comment, you could simply check if `strLine2` contains that string.
3. Don't use string concatenation inside a call to `append`: make two separate calls.

   ```
   wwwdf2.append(strLine2);
   wwwdf2.append("\n");
   ```
4. You don't check if you reach the end of the file. Check if `strLine2` is null, and break the loop if it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the code is not really faster. It still takes minutes to read the file. The text file has over 100000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

My new Created code:(My test device is a Samsung S8)

```
 private void list(){
            String strLine2="";
            wwwdf2 = new StringBuilder();

            InputStream fis2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.list);
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));
            if(fis2 != null) {
                try {
                    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(br2);
                    String linenumber = String.valueOf(lnr);
    int i=0;
                    while (i!=1) {
                        strLine2 = br2.readLine();
                        wwwdf2.append(strLine2);
                        wwwdf2.append("\n");
                        if (wwwdf2.indexOf("itisdonecomplet") >= 0){
                            i++;
                        }


                    }
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strLine2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wwwdf2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do not use indexOf(). Every time it has to go through all the lines again.

Comment: I created an 4MB file with 100000 lines. It is read in 134 ms on one device and in 650 on a small old device. If i add an indexOf() check it takes minutes. Code with a line `if ( line.contains("itisdonecomplet")` will take 156 and 700 ms. The loop is `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`. It is only null after 100000 lines read.

Comment: @blackapps I believe that it will take a lot longer with `indexOf` (single arg) than contains, and in this specific case (where you are adding a newline each time, and searching for a string without a newline) you will get the right answer with `strLine2.contains`. You could still do it with the 2-arg version of indexOf, though, and it would be fast.